# Using extended properties on Events in Office 365 REST API

Tags: java, rest, office365, outlook-restapi

We are in the process of migrating an application that uses the EWS API to the newer [Office 365 REST API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/api-catalog), mainly because it provides more flexible authorization options. The current application uses extended properties to store information (identifiers internal to our applications) on Event objects.

The Office 365 [Message API resource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/APi/complex-types-for-mail-contacts-calendar#RESTAPIResourcesMessage) seems to implement extended properties using `SingleValueExtendedProperties` and `MultiValueExtendedProperties` fields. Is a similar option available for [Event resources](https://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/APi/complex-types-for-mail-contacts-calendar#RESTAPIResourcesEvent)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<s>Extended properties are in preview right now, and they're not currently implemented on Events. We are working on that, so stay tuned. However since this is in preview, bear in mind things could change.</s>

[Extended properties are now available on Events](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/extended-properties-rest-operations#supported-rest-resources).

Comment: Cheers! Any idea on what timeframe this will be available for Events? And possibly a workaround we could use for now?

Comment: There aren't any good workarounds at this point. You could use either the Id or iCalUId as a key that links to identifier in a database or add the identifier in the body of the event. If your users are only using the web client, you could hide the id in a comment in the body. Outlook will show the text.

Comment: Are they implemented on Events as of now, 10/17/2016?

Comment: Yes. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/extended-properties-rest-operations#supported-rest-resources